# Why does vtable function pointers have +1?

Tags: ida, disassembly, arm, vtables

So here is a byte sequence `45 A6 F7` in the `vtable`.
It points to a subroutine which is located at `F7A644`.
IDA expresses it as "function_symbol **+1**"
Why does it plus one?
Why is it `45 A6 F7` rather than `44 A6 F7`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add what architecture (and, if important, what OS) this code is for. At least with the correct tags, and preferably also in the main text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it is ARM architecture that may use THUMB encoding it can be result of the following issue:

If I remember correctly, calls to the virtual functions can be executed with assembly command similar to `BLX` as indirect jump, which allows switching between ARM and THUMB encoding. In this case this `+ 1` means that the target of the jump is encoded in THUMB.

See [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Cihfddaf.html) for more information about this mechanism.

> All these instructions cause a branch to label, or to the address
>   contained in Rm. In addition:
>
> - The BL and BLX instructions copy the address of the next instruction into lr (r14, the link register).
> - The BX and BLX instructions can change the processor state from ARM to Thumb, or from Thumb to ARM. BLX label always changes the state. BX
>     Rm and BLX Rm derive the target state from bit[0] of Rm:
> - if bit[0] of Rm is 0, the processor changes to, or remains in, ARM state
> - if bit[0] of Rm is 1, the processor changes to, or remains in, Thumb state.